# Why does my code terminate without explanation?

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11

I'm learning c++ again after having not touched it for the last few years, and I've run into a rather peculiar bug that I can't seem to figure out.

When I run the code below, it will accept 10 inputs as I expect it to, but immediately after the first `for` loop, the program exits.  I have run it in`gdb`to try and figure out the issue, but it reported that the process 'exited normally'.

I compiled using `g++ -std=c++11`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //User inputs
    string input[10];
    //Get the inputs
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //Get this input
        printf("%i> ", i);
        getline(cin, input[i]);
    }
    //The application does not make it to this point
    //Collected
    printf("Thank you for submitting your data.\n");
    //Print inputs
    for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        //Show the input
        printf("%i> %s\n", a, input[a].c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine [here](https://ideone.com/68wsNx).  Are you running this in an IDE?

Comment: I'm using [c9.io](http://c9.io) to compile the program, and then launch it from the terminal manually.

Comment: Can you add `cin.get();` as the last line of the program and see if that keeps the window open?  If it does the answer below is what you need.

Comment: I would also suggest not using `printf` with `std::string`.  You can output with `std::cout << a << "> " << input[a] << "\n";`

Comment: @NathanOliver The window never closes.  It just goes back to showing `user@host#` on a new line

Comment: Did you try adding the `cin.get()`?  Did you change to using `cout` instead of `printf`?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you're describing, it sounds like stdout is not being flushed before the program ends.  That's unusual; normally, stdout is automatically set up for line-buffered operation in which case it will be flushed as soon as a newline is encountered.

Your best bet is to follow @NathanOliver's advice and use `cout << ...` rather than `printf`.  The `printf` command is a throwback to C, and you're using a C++ compiler and C++ features.  In fact, you're not even including the header that's usually required for `printf`, so I'm a little surprised it even compiles.

FWIW, if you choose to continue using `printf` maybe try manually flushing stdout at the end like so:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application does what is supposed to do:

Application will pause at `getline()` (10 times) (because `getline` is blocking execution), then it will do some for loops, print something and end (probably closing console window). If you add something at the end to block execution (such as `cin.get()`, which waits for enter key press) you will see results (because application won't terminate). If you run your code somewhere where output is not removed after program has ended you will see what was printed.

Comment: The text is not printed at all.  I'm launching the program from within a terminal window, so it's not getting closed at the end.

Comment: It works for me: Firstly `0>` will get printed, then I will 10 times enter input and then it print out all inputs.